# How does "inheritance of methylation" of DNA and/or histones work?

Tags: dna, epigenetics, histone, histone-modifications

What are the current models/ideas describing the mechanisms explaining inheritance of methylation on DNA resp. histone level?

Is there evidance of this "setup" information being really duplicated/inherited during a cell division process?

Pointers? Articles? What is the current state of knowledge regarding this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jon Wilkins has a [nice introduction to imprinting](http://jonfwilkins.blogspot.com/p/primers-on-imprinting.html).  He does a nice job of introducing the idea methylation and how these patterns are maintained during development and cell division.  Further, he links to some interesting papers on the subject.