# Have researchers discovered how epigenetic information is passed down during cell division?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, epigenetics

For example, how are histone code patterns passed down?

This question was asked a few years ago in this thread:

[How are epigenetic marks transmitted during cell division?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5342/how-are-epigenetic-marks-transmitted-during-cell-division)

However, it has been a few years now, and I'd like to know if researchers have made any progress.

**Clarification:**
I'm specifically interested in figuring out how chromatin modifications are epigenetically inherited. There seems to be some evidence that it can be inherited, but there doesn't seem to be a full explanation as to how.

A good source for what I'm talking about is a article published in 2010 called: "Epigenetics and the Origins of Paternal Effects", which goes into detail on experiments done on rats that show epigenetic traits being inherited across offspring. However, the article ended on a note saying that the evidence is speculative, and further research needs to be done.  Here's the link:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2975825/